# Django 1.8 (on Python 3) - Make a SOAP request with pysimplesoap

Tags: php, python, django, web-services, soap

Since one week I'm trying to retrieve some datas from a Dolibarr application including Dolibarr's webservices.

In few words, I'm trying to make a soap request to retrieve user's informations.

At first, I tried to instantiate SoapClient with 'wsdl' and 'trace' parameters, in vain.. SoapClient's object was never been create !

Secondly, I made a made a classical SoapClient's object without 'wsdl', however I used : 'location', 'action', 'namespace', 'soap_ns', 'trace'; It was a success (I think) but It did't work when I called Client's call method.. My dolibarrkey did't match my key on the webservice, but their keys are the same (copy & paste).

For more explanations take a look to dolibarr api (to retrieve datas) with the xlm dataformat.

Link to getUser web service (click on getUser to show parameters): 
http://barrdoli.yhapps.com/webservices/server_user.php

Link to xml dataformat (for the SOAP request maybe):
http://barrdoli.yhapps.com/webservices/server_user.php?wsdl

```
from pysimplesoap.client import SoapClient, SoapFault
import sys

def listThirdParties():
# create a simple consumer
try:
    # client = SoapClient(
    # "[MyAppDomain]/webservices/server_user.php")
    # print(client) 

    # client = SoapClient(wsdl="[MyAppDomain]/webservices/server_user.php?wsdl", trace=True)

    client = SoapClient(
        location = "[myAppDomain]/webservices/server_user.php",
        action = '[myAppDomain]/webservices/server_user.php?wsdl', # SOAPAction
        namespace = "[myAppDomain]/webservices/server_user.php",
        soap_ns='soap',
        trace = True,
    )
    print("connected bitch")
except:
    print("error connect")

message = dict()
message['use'] = "encoded"
message["namespace"] = "http://www.dolibarr.org/ns/"
message["encodingStyle"] = "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"
message["message"] = "getUserRequest"

parts = dict()
auth = dict()

auth['dolibarrkey'] = '********************************'
auth['sourceapplication'] = 'WebServicesDolibarrUser'
auth['login'] = '********'
auth['password'] = '********'
auth['entity'] = ''
parts["authentication"] = auth
parts["id"] = 1
parts["ref"] = "ref"
parts["ref_ext"] = "ref_ext"
message["parts"] = parts

# call the remote method
response = client.call(method='getUser', kwargs=message)

# extract and convert the returned value
# result = response.getUser
# return int(result)
print(response)
pass
```

I've "BAD_VALUE_FOR_SECURITY_KEY" into a xlm response, I think it's my request which made with a bad xml dataformat..

shell response :

```
-------- RESPONSE -------
b'<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><SOAP-ENV:Envelope SOAP-ENV:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:SOAP-ENC="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:tns="http://www.dolibarr.org/ns/"><SOAP-ENV:Body><ns1:getUserResponse xmlns:ns1="http://barrdoli.yhapps.com/webservices/server_user.php"><result xsi:type="tns:result"><result_code xsi:type="xsd:string">BAD_VALUE_FOR_SECURITY_KEY</result_code><result_label xsi:type="xsd:string">Value provided into dolibarrkey entry field does not match security key defined in Webservice module setup</result_label></result><user xsi:nil="true" xsi:type="tns:user"/></ns1:getUserResponse></SOAP-ENV:Body></SOAP-ENV:Envelope>'
```

I really want to know how should I do to make a working soap request with a clean xlm dataformat.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try to setup WebService Security (WSSE) with `client` object? Following examples are taken from https://code.google.com/p/pysimplesoap/wiki/SoapClient

```
client['wsse:Security'] = {
    'wsse:UsernameToken': {
        'wsse:Username': 'testwservice',
        'wsse:Password': 'testwservicepsw',
    }
}
```

or try to Setup AuthHeaderElement authentication header

```
client['AuthHeaderElement'] = {'username': 'mariano', 'password': 'clave'}
```

Comment: Thanks, but I did't works again.. I have the same error 'BAD_VALUE_FOR_SECURITY_KEY' too